# dll loaded with LoadLibrary() is not being accessed, shows the error "dll was not found"

Tags: c, windows, dll, mingw

I'm a something of a beginner in programming. Here's a snippet from a C Program I wrote for Windows, trying to use NCurses library, compiled with mingw32.

```
char NPath[MAX_PATH];
GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, NPath);
char *dllDirectory = malloc(strlen(NPath) + strlen("\\dlls") + 1);
strcpy(dllDirectory, NPath);
strcat(dllDirectory, "\\dlls");
SetDllDirectoryA(dllDirectory);
HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("libncursesw6.dll");
if (!hGetProcIDDLL) {
    printf("libncursesw6.dll could not be loaded!");
    return -1;
} else {
    printf("loaded libncursesw6.dll\n");
}
```

I tried to load the libncursesw6.dll from the *dlls* subfolder, from the same folder of the executable.
The above code works perfectly and displays, the dll is loaded.

But when I try to use use the library functions, I get an error box telling me libncursesw6.dll was not found. The program then works fine if is place the dll with the executable (which is what I'm trying to avoid).

When the following lines are added after the previous snippet, I get a run time error.

```
initscr();
addstr("Hello World");
refresh();
getch();
endwin();
```

I've included the necessary header files and got no compilation errors or warnings.

Am I doing something wrong??

Comment: With MSVC at least, I am pretty sure you can do this with either a manifest file, or writing a custom "helper function". The source code for the default one (`delayhlp.cpp` and `delayimp.h`) is freely provided in the MSVC `include/` directory along with the standard C and C++ headers. I never did it though and don't know if MinGW provides such windows-specific functionality.

Comment: How do you use the functions? Please post all code: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you *load* the library after you have started the program, but if you use the functions in the code, the *runtime linker*, that tries to resolve unresolved symbols, needs to find the library *before* it passes control to the actual program.

So, you cannot do it this way. It would be possible to not use the `ncurses` functions directly, but to define a bunch of function pointers and resolve the symbols you need manually with `GetProcAddress`, but this is quite cumbersome.
For example like this:

```
void (*initscr)() = GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "initscr");
```

Another possibility is, to link the `ncurses` library *statically*, so it isn't needed at runtime.

Comment: Is there a way I can get the dlls working, but loaded from a separate folder?

Comment: @macmahon56 The dlls are searched in the locations mentioned here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa297182(v=vs.100) . Looks like linking ncurses statically is the best option